# need spaces in password editText in android

Tags: android, passwords, space

I need to display space after every 4 characters in password editText in Android.
How I can i do that one please suggest me.

Thanks,

Veerababu

Comment: try several different textviews, may be

Comment: Did you even solve this issue? If so please post the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use TextWatcher and manage Password String

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html
```

Answer (score 0):

this may be your answer...

```
int temp=0;

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start, int before, int count)
{
   if(((s.length()-temp)%4)==0)
   {                        
    et.setText(et.getText().toString()+" ");
    int position = et.getText().toString().length();
    Editable etext = et.getText();
    Selection.setSelection(etext, position);
    temp++;
   }
}
```

Comment: I already did like this but Edit text input type is password, so space also would be changed to dot in password. I just need if the input data is digit then display as password(Dots or astrikes) if the input data is " "(space) then want to display as it is.